# How to display more than 5000 items in a document library on sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a document library which consists of more than 13000 items with some folder structure.I need to display more then 5000 items.I am trying to display using custom view using index (Id) but I am unable display more than 5000 items(may be problem with index because some of the items are deleted). Can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

in sharepoint online you can't change the list view threshold, by defaults its of 5000. But...
You can create a view in your list. Set a filter on the view to filter the data so the total number of items displayed in the view is less than the threshold, based on that filter. 
Then you can query the view.

Regards